# Make Sure Digital pin is high before Serial.write()

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, rs485

I have the following code for a [TTL to RS-485 Adapter Module](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4SR1T56020&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC-_-pla-_-AT+-+Electronics-_-9SIA4SR1T56020&gclid=Cj0KCQjwierMBRCHARIsAHl9i4FHSB6Xl5JEhlYYHC-P1SXYl0Tb-_HCnV8KZf9hBH_MuPIc__QB3kEaAsEZEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

```
[...code]
digitalWrite(DE_PIN, HIGH); //directional control for adapter 
Serial2.write(Message, Size);
Serial2.flush();
digitalWrite(DE_PIN, LOW);  // Set To Recieve
Serial2_reading_foo();
[code...]
```

I've noticed that `DE_PIN` does not seem to go `High` fast enough before `Serial2.write()` executes I confirmed this by adding a small `delay(ms)` which made the code function perfectly.

```
digitalWrite(DE_PIN, HIGH);
delay(100);
Serial2.write(Message, Size);
Serial2.flush();
digitalWrite(DE_PIN, LOW);  // Set To Recieve
delay(100);
Serial2_reading_foo();
```

Unfortunately, there's pretty much [universal agreement](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/arduino-delay-function-shouldnt-use/) that you shouldn't ever use `delay()` in programming. Plus doing any kind of wait function here seems to be insensitive to the real problem. Is there a better way to make sure that `DE_PIN==HIGH` before the Serial2.write() Function begins?

Comment: Short delays are fine. Consider using `delayMicroseconds()` and tuning it for the minimum delay that achieves what you want.

Comment: what is the actual time interval you need? 0.1 s is pretty long for circuits.

Comment: I don't know the true interval. Is there any good way to get it mathematically, or is it just guess and check?

Comment: check the spec sheet of the module

Comment: I couldn't find the spec sheet, but with guess and check, 9ms seems to be the magic number. Is that about right?

Comment: How can you not find the spec sheet? It's the first hit in google for MAX485 - or you go to Maxim's website, look for the MAX485, and click on the datasheet. Anyway, the maximum time you should need is a mere 50ns. Do you have the DE and RE pins tied together?

Comment: The Arduino's IO pins, with no pin load, takes 10.4ns to rise to the 2V needed to register as a HIGH on the DE pin. One clock cycle on the Arduino is 63ns, which is longer than the propagation time for DE. No delay should be needed.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is elsewhere.  Try moving the same amount of delay elsewhere in the loop - maybe what you actually have is a serial message rate or pacing problem.  What is your success/failure verification - are you actually looking at the RS485 on a scope, or are you counting on the unspecified piece of connecting equipment to serially respond or behave in some way as a result??

Answer (score 1):

The MAX485 requires 2V on the DE pin to register a HIGH. It takes no more than an absolute maximum of 50ns for the DE pin to switch the buffers. The Arduino takes 10.4ns for an IO pin to rise to 2V.

That's an absolute maximum of 60.4ns.

One clock cycle of a 16MHz Arduino is 63ns.

That is longer than it takes for the IO pin to tell the MAX485 to switch the buffers.

You can increase that rise time by taking in to account the input capacitance of the MAX485 and the resistance of the connection between the Arduino and the DE pin, but it will still be microscopically small compared to the time between the pin going HIGH and the serial transmission starting.

So there must be something fundamentally wrong with your setup.  Two possibilities spring to mind:

1. You aren't controlling RE, only DE, so RE is floating and is being capacitively linked to DE through the parasitic capacitances of the board and circuitry, making it rise and fall very slowly.
2. You haven't set the IO pin on the Arduino to OUTPUT, so it switches between floating and HIGH through a very high resistance, causing slow rise to HIGH and maybe never getting to LOW at all.

Or a combination of the two.